# Forcing cmake to create 32-bit library instead of 64-bit

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm currently trying to build and link a library for the Raspberry Pi camera in a virtual machine running a Debian 9 image. The library in question can be found at https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam. The library builds fine in the VM, and my program also builds fine, but the linker fails. The build line and error message is (the library in question is `raspicam`):

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o Linux-rpi3/video build/main.cpp.o Linux-rpi3/lib/libvideo.a -lcommon -lclsocket -lGeographic -llog4cplus -lpthread -lshp -lsodium -L./Linux-rpi3/lib -L../common/Linux-rpi3/lib -L../3px/civetweb-1.6/Linux-rpi3 -L../3px/clsockets_1_4_2.mod/Linux-rpi3/lib -L../3px/GeographicLib-1.49/Linux-rpi3/lib -L../3px/libsodium-1.0.3/Linux-rpi3/lib -L../3px/log4cplus-1.1.3-rc3/Linux-rpi3/lib -L../3px/shapelib-1.3.0/Linux-rpi3/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L./3px/raspicam/src -lraspicam
//usr/local/lib/libraspicam.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm reasonably confident that this is a mismatch between a 32-bit program and a 64-bit library. If I run `objdump -a` on the compiled library, it returns

```
libraspicam.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

Meanwhile, if I compile the program without the parts that rely on the library and run `objdump -a` on the executable, it returns

```
video:     file format elf32-little
```

As I'm not hugely familiar with cmake, I don't know the changes I would need to make in the library to get it to build as `elf32-little` in order to get the program to link properly. Is it possible to build this library as 32-bit and if so what do I need to do?

Comment: Library format `elf64-x86-64` is for x86-64 architecture, it is not suitable for ARM. Compiler `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` is a *cross-compiler*, so you need to **cross-compile the library** too. Cross-compiling the project in CMake implies using appropriate **toolchain file**. Just google for appropriate toolchain for your board.